# Doing things on a new page

Tags: javascript

Quick question about going to a new page and doing stuff.

```
// doesn't work
function doThings() {
    document.location.assign("http://foo.com");
    things.doIt();
}
```

`foo.com` has a `things.doIt()` function that I want to invoke after switching to that page, but it appears I can't really do that. Is there an easy way to do this?

And side question, I see everyone using `document.location = url` even though `location` is an object; it appears to work fine but why does everyone use it? Is it faster?

Edit: I can't edit anything on foo.com.

Comment: is there literally no difference? It just feels weird assigning a string to an object.

Comment: No, I don't think it's any differance really. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks, it just bothered me for some reason :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is pass a "referer" or action key in the URL query string so that foo.com can tell if it was arrived at from a specific page or should do something special.  Note: someone could just manually add it to the URL as well though.

http://foo.com?referer=bar.com

or

http://foo.com?action=doIt

Anyway, what you would want is to have a window.onload event handler on foo.com, and inside it have a function to run onload and check if there exists a key in the query string that matches what would be set from the referer, and if so, run things.doIt()

```
window.onload = function(){
  //check the value of location.search for your query string
  //execute special code if so
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without editing it server side? I have a couple small pages with functions and I want to make an extension where I can hit a hotkey on my keyboard from any page and then it takes me to my page and invokes a function. Some of my pages do stuff with clipboard and others with the url from the page I'm coming from, so I can't be sure of the url I'm coming from.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what you mean, where did the server side come from?  Or do you not have access to any of the static files (html, js)

Comment: I mean, is there a way to do it without editing the code on my server (the code on foo.com)? I guess I'm thinking server/client cause I'm making an offline script to do this. I like the idea of passing something in the url (and it seems like it'd definitely work) but it's just that I don't have access to the aws I'm working on until next week and I was hoping to test this this week. Is there anyway for javascript to change location, wait, and then call a function on that page?

Comment: @Peter ah, well that's a pretty important requirement.  I probably would have made a point of stating that in your question that you didn't have access to the actual files.  I guess maybe you could do something that interacts with the console maybe to try and execute JS that way?  I'm not really sure...

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, I'd upvote you if I had 15 rep (or I could remember the password for my other account), it's definitely a correct solution just not the one I can use atm :|

Comment: Figured out the obvious answer. Since I'm writing a user script the browser runs the script every time, so I can just add a special key to the url that doesn't affect anything on the page's side and then have my own onload function in the user script check for that key for specific urls. At least until I get my hands on the html on the server. Thought I'd append this here in case anyone has same problem.

Comment: @Peter cool, glad to hear you were able to come up with something